# My onkeydown() event listener is not working

Tags: jquery

I cannot figure out what's wrong with this code:

```js
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 88) {
          $('.ryu-cool').show()
          $('.ryu-ready').hide()
          $('.ryu-throwing').hide()
          $('.ryu-still').hide()
        }
```

Comment: try logging every key. maybe the key code you're using is wrong? $(document).keydown(function(event) {console.log(event.which);});

Comment: How is it not working? What behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you seeing? Can you also include the HTML?

Comment: You are missing the closing `})` which is why you are getting an "unexpected end of input" error. If you add those in, then pressing x will trigger the function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the full syntax of jquery. Here is a working version on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/used9gfL/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        alert(event.which);
        if (event.which === 88) {
          $('.ryu-cool').show()
          $('.ryu-ready').hide()
          $('.ryu-throwing').hide()
          $('.ryu-still').hide()
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: Please note: A DOM ready handler is not required for `document` as it always exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 88) {
      alert('hi');
    }
    });
```

Explain

on press of key 'x' alert fires, issue is with closing of } braces

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/0gzasd2m/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 88) {
$('.ryu-still').hide();
$('.ryu-ready').hide();
$('.ryu-cool').show();
}   
})
.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 88) { 
$('.ryu-cool').hide();
$('.ryu-still').show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var code = e.which;
  var cxar = String.fromCharCode(code);
  $('body').append(cxar + " = " + code + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click this box and press any key...<br/>
```